# im using ajax but its not executing asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function send(seat_id, seat, seat_name, seat_price, seat_class){

      if(ing_order_yn == "y"){
            alert("결제창 이동 중 입니다. 좌석 변경이 불가능합니다.");

            return false;

        }       
        var data1_val = "";    
        var data1_val_f = "";    
        var e_id    = $('input[name=e_id]').val();  //사용자가 선택한 event_id    
        var floor   = $('input[name=floor_value]').val();//층    
        var seat_list;   

        $.ajax({
            url: '/seat_catch.do?group_id=<%=group_id%>',    
            type : 'POST',    
            data : { 'event_id' : e_id, 'seat_id' : seat_id },    
            datatype : 'html',    
            async : true,    
            success : function( data1 ){    
                    data1_val = data1.trim().substring(0,4);    
                    data1_val_f = data1.trim().substring(0,6); //[선택불가] 
                    //로그인 세션이없는 경우 ajax 리턴 값은 "session_out" 이다.

                    if(data1.trim() == "session_out"){
                        alert('로그아웃 된 상태입니다.\n로그인 후 사용해 주시기 바랍니다.')

                        document.location.href="/login.do";

                    }else{              
                            if(data1_val == "담기성공"){        
                            document.getElementById(seat).className  = "sel";    

                                //클릭 한 좌석 정보 레이어 보여주기

                                $('#msg_popup2').html(seat_name + "<br>" + seat_price +"원");    
                                    $('#msg_popup2').show();    
                                    $('#msg_popup2').delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);    
                                var e_id = $('input[name=e_id]').val(); //사용자가 선택한 event_id  
                                    //좌석 선점 처리 후. 좌석 현행화
                                    orderSeatOp(e_id,'1',floor, function(htmll)
                                        alert(htmll);    
                                        $('#seat').html(htmll);    
                                    });       
                                    <%-- $.ajax({
                                        url : '/seat.do',    
                                        type : 'POST',    
                                        async : true,    
                                        data : { 'event_id' : e_id ,'group_id' : <%=group_id%> , 'floor' : floor },

                                        success : function( res ){
                                        $('#seat').html(res); 

                                        return false;    
                                    }

                                });

                             --%>
```

I think it has a problem in code for last section.
I did this two way

1. one way is ajax code(annotating in last section)
2. callback function.

`$('#seat').html(res);` it takes whole jsp code of layer popup and makes refresh. I want to make it as asynchronously but it still execute for refresh.
I don't know what can I do. please help me.
and sorry for my shortly English.

Comment: Add console log in the begining of the callback; right before the 2nd ajax call; and inside the success of the 2nd ajax call and double check

Comment: maybe you can change the data type to json and see if it's working

Comment: and make sure you return json data back to the client side

Comment: thx for your reply guys!! I resolve this prob!! Its very simply prob than my thought. I cut that res code which i want!! than its working!!